# MathJax Equations displays vertical line on the right, How to remove?

Tags: moodle, mathjax

MathJax Equations displays vertical line on the right, How to remove ?

[MathJax Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TljHd.png)

Mathjax cdn 2.7.1
Moodle version 2.6

Comment: You might want to post a live example exhibiting the problem.

Comment: kindly refer attached images . one more pretty things  vertical line not coming in firebox browser , mathjax equation rendering is browser compatible   ?

Comment: Again there's little to tell from that picture and there is no known bug. Without a live sample, there's no way of debugging the issue. It's quite possible the problem isn't with MathJax itself but other parts of the page.

Comment: There was a [similar issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1300) in MathJax v2.5 in Chrome, but that was fixed in MathJax v2.6.  Are you *sure* you are using version 2.7.1?

Comment: Due to lower version of MathJax library in Moodle then i changed library MathJax V2.2 to V2.7.1 in Moodle filter now vertical line not appears in every equations. MathJax is not browser compatible Thanks .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to lower version of MathJax library in Moodle then i changed library MathJax **V2.2 to V2.7.1** in Moodle filter now vertical line not appears in every equations. MathJax is not browser compatible Thanks guys.